# My DFS graph methods won't go from int to String

Tags: java, data-structures

I wrote a StringfromInt method to change my ints to Airports. When I implemented the method into those methods with the ints everything worked out great! But when I implemented the same method into my DFS graph methods the output doesn't look all that good.

```
 public void printPaths(int s, int d)  
 { 

     boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[numVertices]; 
     ArrayList<Integer> pathList = new ArrayList<>(); 

     //add source to path[] 
     pathList.add(s); 

     System.out.println("\n"); 
     //Call recursive utility 
     printAllPathsUtil(s, d, isVisited, pathList); 
 }  

 void printAllPaths(String s, String d) {
     int start=airportsHashMap.get(s).intValue();
        int end=airportsHashMap.get(d).intValue();
         System.out.println("Print all Paths: " +s + "-->"); 
         for(Integer pCrawl: adjListArray[airportsHashMap.get(s)]){ 
             System.out.print(airportFromInt(pCrawl) + "\t"); 
         } 
        printPaths(start,end);


 }

 private void printAllPathsUtil(Integer u, Integer d, 
                                 boolean[] isVisited, 
                         List<Integer> localPathList) { 

     // Mark the current node 
     isVisited[u] = true; 

     if (u.equals(d))  
     { 
         System.out.println(localPathList); 
         // if match found then no need to traverse more till depth 
         isVisited[u]= false; 
         return ; 
     } 

     // Recur for all the vertices 
     // adjacent to current vertex 
     for (Integer i :adjListArray[u])  
     { 
         if (!isVisited[i]) 
         { 
             // store current node  
             // in path[] 
             localPathList.add(i);
             printAllPathsUtil(i, d, isVisited, localPathList); 

             // remove current node 
             // in path[] 
             localPathList.remove(localPathList.size()-1);
         } 
     } 

     // Mark the current node 
     isVisited[u] = false; 
 } 
 /*
     * This method will facilitate doing a reverse look up from
     * the HashMap object.  Since the HashMap has a String key and
     * integer value, we can't look things up by the value.
     */
//Method that converts ints to Strings
 private String airportFromInt(int airportInt) {
        // TODO: Write body of airportFromInt method
    //
     String AirInts = null;
     if (airportInt == 0) 
     {
         AirInts ="JFK";
     }
     if (airportInt == 1)
     {
         AirInts = "EWR";
     }
        if (airportInt == 2)
        {
            AirInts = "PHL";
        }
        if (airportInt == 3)
        {
            AirInts = "ILG";
        } 
        if (airportInt == 4 )
        {
            AirInts = "IAD";
        }
        return AirInts;
    }

}
```

The output for the above code is supposed to be

```
All paths between EWR and PHL 

EWR IAD ILG PHL EWR IAD PHL EWR PHL 


All paths between EWR and ILG 

EWR IAD ILG EWR IAD PHL ILG EWR PHL ILG EWR PHL IAD ILG
```

BUT i'm getting :

```
Print all Paths: EWR-->
IAD PHL 

[1, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 4, 2]
[1, 2]
Print all Paths: EWR-->
IAD PHL 

[1, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

How exactly can I fix this issue? I want to change the ints to strings and match the correct output

Comment: ...What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, I want to match the correct output and change those ints to strings

Answer (score 0):

You are using your `airportFromInt` function to display "Print all Paths: EWR--> IAD PHL", but you are not using it in your `printAllPathsUtil` function where you have `System.out.println(localPathList);`.

Comment: How would I implement it in that function?

Comment: Instead of printing the list of numbers in one go with `System.out.println(localPathList);`, iterate through your list and call your `airportFromInt` function on each int in the list. Also, in the `airportFromInt` function you may want to replace all the `if` statements with a `switch` statement.

Comment: ok I think I'm close so I changed up the loop a bit and I put it in the function printAllPathsUtil. So I put it as this                                                                                                             System.out.println(airportFromInt(v) + "-->"); 
   for(Integer pCrawl: adjListArray[v]){ 
    System.out.print(airportFromInt(pCrawl) + "\t"); 
   }

Comment: it looks like this now:PHL-->
ILG IAD EWR PHL-->
ILG IAD EWR PHL-->
ILG IAD EWR 

ILG-->
IAD PHL ILG-->
IAD PHL ILG-->
IAD PHL ILG-->
IAD PHL

Comment: Well done. You might want to edit your post or add an answer showing what the problem/solution was.